# A ftp server that automatically backup files downloaded by users

Tags: backup, ftp

If I want to setup a ftp server (using CentOS 7) which can automatically and implicitly duplicate/save the files its ftp user downloads, how should I do?
For example, a valid ftp user may download some files. I'd like to have that server to automatically copy those files to some folder for backup or log purpose.
Is this possible?

Comment: *"I'd like to have that server automatically copy those files to some folder for backup or log purposes.*" - A bit confused here. You mean the files themselves or just the file names? Because the former would seem to potentially involve a lot of wasted disk space.

Comment: Well, I really mean to "copy those files to some folder" rather than copy those file names only. Such backup serves as a record for security reason.